# Como puedo guardar los checkbox que marquen en la base de datos, laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Buenas tengo un inconveniente al querer guardar los checkbox de un form en el metodo store de laravel, les dejo lo que tengo hasta ahora.

**Formulario**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">KPI</label>

<div class="demo-checkbox" style="margin-top:1%">
    <input type="checkbox" name="kpi[dni]" id="kpi_dni" class="filled-in jqcheck" />
    <label for="kpi_dni">DNI</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="kpi[ruc]" id="kpi_ruc" class="filled-in jqcheck" />
    <label for="kpi_ruc">RUC</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="kpi[pos]" id="kpi_pos" class="filled-in jqcheck" />
    <label for="kpi_pos">POS</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="kpi[out]" id="kpi_out" class="filled-in jqcheck" />
    <label for="kpi_out">OUTDOOR</label>
</div>
```

Este es mi formulario, dentro del cual tengo mis checkbox.

Quiero que cuando el check este marcado me guarde 1 en la caja correspondiente.
[image: Esta es una parte de la base de datos, eso deseo.]

**Controlador**

public function store(Request $request)
    {

```
    $contract = new Contract();
    $contract->client= $client->id;
    $contract->java = $request->input('java');
    $contract->method_payment = $request->input('method_payment');
    $contract->kpi_dni =$request->kpi['dni'];
    $contract->kpi_ruc =$request->kpi['ruc']==on?:off;
    $contract->kpi_pos =$request->kpi['pos'];
    $contract->kpi_out =$request->kpi['out'];

    print_r($contract);die();
    $contract->save();
}
```

Veo que si captura el checkbox, lo que pasa es que me captura on, y bueno no hay problema podria almacenarlo asi, pero por ejemplo cuando no selecciono un checkbox no se como guardarlo, ya que no me trae nada, ademas trate de verificar si esta on, sino pasar off e igual no da nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: serías tan amable de colocar el código que estas manejando en el controlador, para intentar almacenar esta información? así como indicarnos los errores que se te han presentado?

Comment: Listo compañero, lo agrege.

Answer (score 0):

Al final decidí por darle un name a cada uno de forma distinta:

```
<div class="demo-checkbox" style="margin-top:1%">
<input type="checkbox" name="kpi_dni" id="kpi_dni" class="filled-in jqcheck" />
<label for="kpi_dni">DNI</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="kpi_ruc" id="kpi_ruc" class="filled-in jqcheck" />
<label for="kpi_ruc">RUC</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="kpi_pos" id="kpi_pos" class="filled-in jqcheck" />
<label for="kpi_pos">POS</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="kpi_out" id="kpi_out" class="filled-in jqcheck" />
<label for="kpi_out">OUTDOOR</label>
```

La forma de leerlo en mi controlador tambien cambio:

```
    $contract->kpi_dni =$request->input('kpi_dni');
    $contract->kpi_ruc =$request->input('kpi_ruc');
    $contract->kpi_pos =$request->input('kpi_pos');
    $contract->kpi_out =$request->input('kpi_out');
```

Y al final por jquery cambio el value del input para recibir 1 o 0 segun se active o no.

```
$('.jqcheck').change(function(){
            //Validando POS
            if( $('#kpi_pos').is(':checked'))
            {
                $('#pos').val("10");
                $('#kpi_pos').val("1");
                console.log("POS 1");
            }else{
                $('#pos').val("0");
                $('#kpi_pos').val("0");
                console.log("POS 0");
            }

            //Validando solo DNI
            if( $('#kpi_dni').is(':checked'))
            {
                $('#kpi_ruc').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('#ruc').val("0");
                $('#flat').val("30");
                console.log("DNI 1");
            }else{
                $('#kpi_ruc').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('#flat').val("0");
                console.log("DNI 0");
            }

            //Validando solo RUC
            if( $('#kpi_ruc').is(':checked'))
            {
                $('#kpi_dni').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('#ruc').val("10");
                $('#flat').val("30");
                console.log("RUC 1");
            }else{
                $('#kpi_dni').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('#kpi_ruc').val("0");
                $('#kpi_flat').val("0");
                console.log("RUC 0");
            }

            //Validando OUTDOOR
            if( $('#kpi_out').is(':checked'))
            {
                $('#outdoor').val("60");
                $('#flat').val("0");
                console.log("OUT 1");
            }else{
                $('#outdoor').val("0");
                console.log("OUT 0");
            }

            suma();
        });
```